# Ajax create new DIV instead of refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a problem with this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            (function update() {
                $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "http://192.168.4.2/home/api/stato/ambiente/living",
                dataType: "json", 
                success: renderList
                }).then(function() {           
                    setTimeout(update, 200);  
                });
            })();                              

            function renderList(data) {
                var list = data == null ? [] : (data instanceof Array ? data : [data]);
                $.each(list, function(index, data) {
                    if (data.stato ==1) {
                        $('#statoList').append('<div>'+ data.ID + " " + data.descrizione + " <img src=img/lamp_on.png " + '</div>');
                        $('#Switch').append('<button type="button">' + " OFF " + '</button>');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#statoList').append('<div>'+ data.ID + " " + data.descrizione + " <img src=img/lamp_off.png " + '</div>');
                        $('#Switch').append('<button type="button">' + " ON " + '</button>');
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>  

        <div id="statoList"></div>
        <div id="Switch"></div>

    </body>

</html>
```

I wish to execute a DIV refresh every 200 ms but the problem is that each time creates a new DIV below the previous one.

How can I solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are more than one of each type  [**`empty()`**](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) the containers before appending

```
 $('#statoList').empty();
 $.each(list, function(index, data) {
       if (data.stato ==1) {...
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried but always shows only the last result

Comment: OK...then whole question needs clarification. Using append would show all results from latest set of data. If you need some of the existing to be kept then not clear at all how your data works

Comment: Sorry, this is the response from GET if can help: [{"ID":"S_I_01","stato":"1","ambiente":"living","tipo":"illuminazione","descrizione":"Illuminazione Soggiorno 1"},{"ID":"S_I_02","stato":"1","ambiente":"living","tipo":"illuminazione","descrizione":"Illuminazione Soggiorno 2"}]

Comment: Well using `append()` the same way you are currently doing should show all results in that data. If expectations are different then it needs to be explained by updating question with both the data sample and explanation

Answer (score 6):

the append function is not the right one for what you are expecting i suggest you to use .html() so it will translate all your code (new div) to an html code

```
function renderList(data) {
                var list = data == null ? [] : (data instanceof Array ? data : [data]);
                $.each(list, function(index, data) {
                    if (data.stato ==1) {
                        $('#statoList').html('<div>'+ data.ID + " " + data.descrizione + " <img src=img/lamp_on.png " + '</div>');
                        $('#Switch').html('<button type="button">' + " OFF " + '</button>');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#statoList').html('<div>'+ data.ID + " " + data.descrizione + " <img src=img/lamp_off.png " + '</div>');
                        $('#Switch').html('<button type="button">' + " ON " + '</button>');
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Will only display last item of each type if array has more than one of each

Comment: Oh thanks! I get it! However, as mentioned by charlietfl, it shows only the last result .